# I have a String Error for local path video for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, avplayer

I have a string error with a local video file to the AVPlayer

The bottom line of the videoItem flags up with

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type
>   'String'

Would really appreciate some help on this!

when i disable certain bits of the page code, i can get one of the tracking images to recognise ok, but i cannot get them both to be recognised in the same build.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

        let node = SCNNode()



       if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {


            let fileString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "black", ofType: "mp4")

            let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileString))
```

full code here

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit



class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    var FreemensNode: SCNNode?
    var VideoNode: SCNNode?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true


        let FreemensScene = SCNScene(named: "ar.scnassets/Freemens.scn")
        let VideoScene = SCNScene(named: "ar.scnassets/Video.scn")
        FreemensNode = FreemensScene?.rootNode
        VideoNode = VideoScene?.rootNode




    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()


        if let trackingImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos", bundle: Bundle.main){

        configuration.trackingImages = trackingImages
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 2

        }

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate





    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

        let node = SCNNode()



       if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {


        if let fileString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "black", ofType: "mp4") {
            let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileString))


            let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: videoItem)
            //initialize video node with avplayer
            let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)

            player.play()
            // add observer when our player.currentItem finishes player, then start playing from the beginning
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                player.play()
                print("Looping Video")
            }

            // set the size (just a rough one will do)
            let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 360))
            // center our video to the size of our video scene
            videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
            // invert our video so it does not look upside down
            videoNode.yScale = -1.0
            // add the video to our scene
            videoScene.addChild(videoNode)


            // Create a plane
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "Tracker" {
                // Set AVPlayer as the plane's texture and play
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene

            } else if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "Vuforia" {
               plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)


            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

            }

            var shapeNode: SCNNode?
            switch imageAnchor.referenceImage.name {
            case ArItem.Freemens.rawValue :
                shapeNode = FreemensNode

            case ArItem.Video.rawValue :
                shapeNode = VideoNode
            default:
                break

            }



            if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "Vuforia" {
                 shapeNode = FreemensNode


            } else if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "Tracker"{
                shapeNode = VideoNode



            }

            guard let shape = shapeNode else { return nil}
            node.addChildNode(shape)
        }

        return node

    }

    enum ArItem : String {
        case Freemens = "Freemens"
        case Video = "Video"
    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error,

> Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type
>   'String'

**Reason:**

`path(forResource:ofType:)` returns a `String?`. Hence, `fileString` is of type `String?`.

**Solution:**

So, you need to `unwrap` it before using it in `AVPlayerItem(url:)` like,

```
if let fileString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "black", ofType: "mp4") {
    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileString))
}
```

**Edit:**

You need to `return` `node` or `nil` from `renderer(_:, nodeFor:)` method.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    let node = SCNNode()
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {            
        if let fileString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "black", ofType: "mp4") {
            let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileString))
        }
        return node
    }
    .
    .
    .
    return nil //here.....
}
```

**Edit-2:**

In your code, add `return nil` statement after the `enum` you've created, i.e.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    //Your code here...
    enum ArItem : String {
        case Freemens = "Freemens"
        case Video = "Video"
    }
    return nil //Here.............
}
```

Comment: many thanks for replying @PGDev, I have done that, but it now leads to an error that I do not understand

Comment: `code`Missing return in a function expected to return 'SCNNode?'`code`

Comment: You need to return `node` or `ni`l from `renderer(_:, nodeFor:)`  method.

Comment: Add `return nil` after your enum definition ends.

Comment: Hi PGDev, it isn't. I tried to paste the full page code to the comment, but its not letting me. is there some other way i can send it to you.

Comment: Paste it in your question itself.

Comment: You added it to my answer earlier. That's why I rejected that. Edit your question and add it over there.

Comment: Update the answer. You just need to add a `return nil` statement to remove the compiler error.

Comment: It builds, and the ARKit enables with the scene that is related to Vuforia and Freemens loads the 3d object over the tracking image, but the "homer video" that is meant to overlay over the "tracker" image doesn't intitialise when you put the camera over it.

Comment: I think the question you asked is resolved here. In can you have other other requirements, ask a separate question and mark the answer accepted(tick on left). Happy coding..